# How to get an array of a specific property of an object from an array of objects using filter() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I am trying to learn Javascript specifically the method, "filter()". I want to get an array of names from an array of objects. It just returns the same array of objects passed as an argument. What am I missing?

Update: I confused filter() with map(). I am sorry to waste people's time.

```
personsObj = {
 persons: [{name: "Baig",age: 14},{name: "HenTie", age: 20}]
}

switchButtonHandler = (personsArray) => {
  var names = this.personsArray.persons.filter((obj) => obj.name);
  console.log(names);
}
```

Comment: specifically, `filter` is the wrong tool for the job.   You need `map`.

Comment: `.filter()` takes an array and potentially returns *less of the items*. It's filtering them by some predicate you supply. It doesn't *transform* the items, that is the job of `.map()`

Comment: p.s. either the name `personsArray` or the use of `{ ... }` is wrong, because the latter is an _object_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are trying to do is `map` an array to an array of other thing. In your case:

```js
const personsArray = {
 persons: [{name: "Baig",age: 14},{name: "HenTie", age: 20}]
}

const newArray = personsArray.persons.map(person => person.name) // use proper name

console.log(newArray)
```

Map is intended to transform an array into other different array and filter is intended to return an array based on a condition, like in this case "give me all the people with age higher than 18", so you could do:

```js
const personsArray = {
 persons: [{name: "Baig",age: 14},{name: "HenTie", age: 20}]
}

const adults = personsArray.persons.filter(person => person.age > 18)

console.log(adults)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing the confusion!!